# turning an input into a string into a integer

Tags: python-3.x, integer

I am writing some code that takes in user input via text prompt, (command line.) the goal with this code is to take the users input, make sure it meets some requirements, then use it to edit other variables. Here is the code, (slightly altered the names of the input and variables:)

```
import os

command = 0
cmd = input(">")
command = int(cmd)
if command <= 0:
    print("That number is too low.")
    os.exit(1)
elif command >= 11:
    print("That number is too high.")
    os.exit(1)
else:
example1 = command
example2 = command + example1
```

However, when this runs it claims there is `unorderable types: str() <= int()`.
Since this code doesn't work, could someone help fix it or tell me another way to convert input into an integer? I am using Python 3+.

Comment: That does/would  not happen with the code you have presented. Are you sure you don't have cmd in place of command somewhere?

Comment: I am sure but it is still giving me that error. Instead of giving me the line number of the calculation, however, it gave me the line that gives the variable command it's value. (Line 5 in this instance.)

Comment: Well you must be running a different script or else you did not save it after you modified it.

Comment: I didnt put in the else into my actual script. sorry for the confusion.

Comment: The else would make no difference, on another note there is no `os.exit`, did you mean `os._exit`?

Answer (score 0):

```
import os

command = int(input(">"))

if command <= 0:
    print("That number is too low.")
    os.exit(1)
elif command >= 11:
    print("That number is too high.")
    os.exit(1)
else:
    example1 = command
    example2 = command + example1
```